# How to save instance state of AsyncTask on Android 

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My program record network traffic by using tcpdump command, _initTask execute the tcpdump command.
I lose the object _initTask when I exit the application,
after back to the application I am not able to reach _initTask object to be able to stop the task.
How to save _initTask instance state?

```
protected InitTask _initTask;

public void OnClickRecord(View view) throws IOException {
    ....

    Log.e("AndroLoad class::OnClickRecord", "AsyncTask will start");
    _initTask = new InitTask();
    _initTask.execute(this);

    } else {
        ....
    }

}
```

Could I do that with `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` or `OnPause()` ? if yes, please provide an example.

Comment: Could you explain your question a bit better? WHat are you trying to accomplish? Yeah, you can definitely save the task by returning it in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`. However, you should explain what you want a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

> My program record network traffic by using tcpdump command

Android is not well-suited for running command-line programs.

> _initTask execute the tcpdump command

Why? `tcpdump` is a command. It runs in its own process. It will run indefinitely, or until a specified number of packets are caught, or until you send a SIGINT or SIGKILL to it. An `AsyncTask` makes no sense in this scenario.

> I lose the object _initTask when I exit the application

Of course. You should be stopping `tcpdump` in `onDestroy()` of whatever component forked that process.

> How to save _initTask instance state?

You don't. You should be stopping `tcpdump` in `onDestroy()` of whatever component forked that process.